# error _x is not a member of gazebo::math::Pose

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am using the following :
math::Pose A = this->model->GetWorldPose();
while(A._x!= pointB[0] && A._y!=pointB[1] && A._z!=pointC[2])
do something

on compiling i am getting the error,
‘class gazebo::math::Pose’ has no member named ‘_x’
‘class gazebo::math::Pose’ has no member named ‘_y’
‘class gazebo::math::Pose’ has no member named ‘_z’

But the API[1] does show _x _y and _z as double members of math::Pose.

[1]http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.0.0/classgazebo_1_1math_1_1Pose.html#a89b25f91820943a4d887120a7588e61f

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12734/error-_x-is-not-a-member-of-gazebo::math::pose/) by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should try to access these values with :

```
A.pos.x
```

https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1math_1_1Pose.html

https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1math_1_1Vector3.html

---

Originally posted by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) with karma: 284 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on 2016-02-29**:
Thanks !!!!